# PHP extractTo does not extract files properly on one computer, but works on the other.

Tags: php, wamp, php-ziparchive

I'm facing a very weird problem! I'm using the method below to extract a .zip file's contents into a new folder. It works perfectly fine one my computer but does not work on another one! I have Windows XP on both computers and have installed the same wampServer on both. Everything between the two computers is the same except their CPU and RAM! My computer is a powerful one and the one where the extract process fails is a very slow computer. Is that why? How can I make sure the PHP code runs perfectly even in a slow environment?

One thing to add: the zip archive to be extracted contains one directory and some files in that directory. If I test the process with a zip file that has no directories in it, it works fine on both computers. Any ideas?!

```
public function extract($pluginName, $pasteLocation) {

    $zip = new ZipArchive(); 
    $plugin = $pasteLocation.$pluginName.".zip";

    if ($zip->open($plugin) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($pasteLocation);
        $zip->close();
        unlink($pasteLocation.$pluginName.'.zip');
        $status = "true";
        $msg = "success";
    } else {
        $status = "false";
        $msg = "error";
    }

    $result["status"] = $status;
    $result["msg"] = $msg;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it does not work in one system. Can you tell what is not working, like, are the files extracted partially? or are the files getting corrupted?

Did you tried using different directories. Does the target directory contain a file with the same name as the directory in the zip? then I guess directory creation will not work.

Also what version of php are you using?

EDIT: Did you use ZipArchive::getStatusString  function to get any generated errors ? Are you using the same source archive in both machines?

You can also try the procedure explained in comment by 'hardcorevenom' [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php.).

You can also try this class as shown [here](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip) if nothing works.

Comment: I'm using php V 5.3.8.   apache V2.2.21 and the zip files contains one direcrory named "INFO" inside it there are two files, "INFO.swf" and "INFO.xml". they are extracted corrupted! and sometimes the swf extracts 0kb and the xml not extracted at all and sometimes vice versa!!!